# How to merge two records via REST?

Tags: rest-api, merge

Both [Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_merge.htm) and [SOAP APIs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_merge.htm) provide a method to merge two records of a mergeable type (e.g., Account, Contact).  Is there any way to access this functionality from a REST API?  I've checked the docs and poked around Workbench but I haven't found anything.

Comment: I suspect it isn't currently (v47.0) possible as `MergeRequest` isn't exposed via the REST  API.

Comment: Can't you write a REST enabled stub using APEX and then call that method from outside Salesforce? That might be something to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No as of June 2023, REST doesn't support Merge requests as standard API. SOAP is your option as it will generate WSDL and have sessions to allow merges more securely.

Alternatively, you can create a web service at Salesforce, and access it using REST, but it will be a custom work.